# How to access direct product URL with (Not Visible Individual) in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I need a help in magento 1.9.x
I want access Product details page via URL but Product not visible in searching and Category so for that i use 'Not Visible Individual' in Visibility section when create product from backend.

So i can't understand what i do.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Either You have to change visibility to "Catalog Search" OR Add this simple product to any configurable product.